# How to convert spectral density to amplitude

Tags: r, signals, fft

I have standard periodogram produced from the spectrum function call in the R "stats" package. It produces a spectral density on the Y axis. I wish to actually inspect the amplitude of the key frequency signals.

How do i convert the spectral density to an amplitude? Is there a periodgram plot/analysis in R that produces a frequency vs amplitude plot automatically? Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use different terminology than I do. The help page says that value returned from the spectrum function is a list whose first two elements are:

```
freq    
vector of frequencies at which the spectral density is estimated. 
(Possibly approximate Fourier frequencies.) The units are the reciprocal 
of cycles per unit time (and not per observation spacing): see ‘Details’

spec    
Vector (for univariate series) or matrix (for multivariate series) of 
estimates of the spectral density at frequencies corresponding to freq.
```

So is the `$spec` element what you are calling the vector of "amplitudes"? (You haven't said what the "key frequency signals" are so I just picked the fourth frequency from the example in `?spectrum`:

```
 lh.spec <- spectrum(lh)

 lh.spec$freq[4]
#1] 0.08333333
  lh.spec$spec[4]
#[1] 1.167519
```

Comment: Thank-you @DWin for your response. I have no problem extracting the spectral density values "spec" vector, but, the value of the spectral density is presumably in some form of power units. I want to convert the spectral density into the corresponding amplitude of the sine signal. Is there an easy conversion?